# Mathematical function inside user-defined function in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a function that accepts a list of integers as one argument and a simple mathematical function as a second. Then I want to run the math function on the integers and put the results into a second function. Here is the outline for what I am looking for:

```
def func(test_cases, function_of_n): #test_cases=[10, 50, 100], function_of_n can be n/10, n/20, sqrt(n), etc.
    for n in test_cases:
        a = function_of_n(n)
        second_function(n, a)
```

The problem I am having is I do not know how to put in the simple math functions. I've found one way to solve this is to make many different functions, like so:

```
def func1(test_cases): #test_cases=[10, 50, 100], function_of_n can be n/10, n/20, sqrt(n), etc.
    for n in test_cases:
        a = n/10
        second_function(n, a)

def func2(test_cases): #test_cases=[10, 50, 100], function_of_n can be n/10, n/20, sqrt(n), etc.
    for n in test_cases:
        a = n**2
        second_function(n, a)

def func3(test_cases, function_of_n): #test_cases=[10, 50, 100], function_of_n can be n/10, n/20, sqrt(n), etc.
    for n in test_cases:
        a = numpy.sqrt(n)
        second_function(n, a)
```

This works, but I'm guessing there's a much better way to do this than copy and paste the code and make that small change each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What?

```
func(test_cases, lambda x: x / 10)
func(test_cases, lambda x: x ** 2)
func(test_cases, numpy.sqrt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass functions as arguments just like you would pass variables:

```
def second_function(x, y):
    print x, y

def multi(x):
    return x*10

def func(test_cases, function_of_n):
    for n in test_cases:
        a = function_of_n(n)
        second_function(n, a)


func([1,2,3,4], multi)
```

I would also suggest checking out [lambda functions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk)